# React: The existing value of my text input gets cleared when onChange event occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs. I'm trying to make a page where the user can edit their own post. So, the value of the text input are given from which the users entered when posting the post. Now when I try to change the existing text in the text input, the value which is available in the form gets cleared and user has to enter the data freshly.

I need the user to change the existing text in the input text instead of entering it freshly. Here's my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class EditProduct extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            product: []
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/lender/edit_product_display.php?id=" + this.props.match.params.productId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((productResponse) => {
                this.setState({
                   product: productResponse
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    handleChange(event){
        const name = event.target.name

        this.setState({
            product: [{
                [name]: event.target.value
            }]
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div key={this.state.product.product_id}>
                Product ID: {this.props.match.params.productId}
                <br /><br />
                Product Name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="product_name"
                    value={this.state.product.product_name}
                    onChange= {this.handleChange}
                />

                <br />
                Product Model:
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="product_model"
                    value={this.state.product.product_model}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                 />
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default EditProduct
```

Comment: Your value `value={this.state.product.product_name}` doesnt match your structure you are using for your state, ie product is set as an array `product: []` your value would need to reflect that, eg `this.state.product[0].product_name` or change your state structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only merges state automatically at top-level. It won't merge inside of `product` for you, so you have to do it yourself:

```
    handleChange(event){
        const name = event.target.name
        const value = event.target.value

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            product: {
                ...prevState.product,
                [name]: value
            }
        }))
    }
```

Comment: Still my text input clears the existing value and the whole state gets updated again freshly :(

Comment: @SarathDev Oh, I see now. I left an unnecessary array in there. Try now.

Comment: Finally works! I've been sitting on this for a long time. Thanks a lot :) You made my day! :D